# Both apt and yum will try to install a kernel upgrade when there is not enough space, and fail, leaving the latest kernel unbootable

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, apt, yum

I've encountered this with `apt` on ubuntu and `yum` on centos 7.

Coupled with many linux install guides stating "you only need a few hundred Mb for the /boot partition", this is a minor disaster.   It's recoverable if you know what you're doing, but for someone who doesn't know which files in /boot can be removed by hand, it is a big problem.

Even removing old kernels, there's some sort of accretion after a several months of weekly kernel updates such that /boot will eventually get too full to install anymore updates without such a failure.   Even pared down to 1 kernel.

Other than obviously making your `/boot` partition 500-1000Mb to give some breathing room, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: This should help: http://askubuntu.com/a/153193/225694 Another option would be to keep /boot on your root partition rather than it's own (unless that's equally space restricted)